# Am I wrong ? (2)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be the space of real continous functions on $[0,1]$. $X$ is a Banach space with the two norms 
$$|f|_\infty=\sup_{s\in[0,1]}|f(s)|$$
and
$$|f|_2=\left(\int_0^1|f(s)|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$
The canonical map $(X,|.|_\infty)\to (X,|.|_2):f\mapsto f$  is a bounded bijective operator since
$$|f|_2\leq |f|_\infty.$$
Then by the "Bounded inverse theorem" the inverse of this map is also continuous and we have a constant $c>0$  such that
$$|f|_\infty\leq c|f|_2.$$
I feel something is wrong in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $X$ is not a Banach space when equipped with the second norm (the $L^2$ norm). The continuous functions are dense in $L^2$. They aren't closed, so they aren't a Banach space.